# windows form design Ruined when connect to excel

Tags: c#, excel, winforms

when i connect to excel file with this code (exactly when _conn.Open();)

```
                _conn = new OleDbConnection(_connectionStrting);
                _conn.Open();
                DataTable dt = _conn.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
                String[] sheetNames = new String[dt.Rows.Count];
                int i = 0;

                foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
                {
                    sheetNames[i] = row["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();
                    comboBox2.Items.Add(sheetNames[i]);
                    i++;
                }

                _conn.Close();
```

my windows form design(in c#) gets some problems like resolution changes and element size is getting smaller than before and place of elements changes in run time .i use an other way to connect to excel(using Excel library) and now i don't have problem.but i am Curious about this problem.can some one told me why this happen?

Comment: can u show screenshots...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This bug has haunted many developers!

A user posted an example on YouTube here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zdby6gmbX_4

SOLUTION:
If you uninstall the "Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable" 32 bit version and then install the 64 bit version. You then uninstall the 64 bit version and then reinstall the 32 bit version it will now work